# What is the reciprocal verb of "to thank"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I know that *to express gratitude* or *to thank* are verbs that basically mean *to say thank you*, but what is the verb for the reciprocol action (i.e. saying *you're welcome*)?

Is there a word for this, and does it vary based on the response?
Like if I say *thank you* and you say *go to H-E-double hockey sticks!*. What did you **do** other than *reply*?

In short:

> "Thank you" = *to thank*
>   "You're welcome" = to *???*

Comment: "Go to H-E-double hockey sticks!"... Err, non-sequitur?

Comment: I guess he means the letter _L_. Double it, and you get the double hockey sticks. **:-)**

Comment: Ah yes, I think you're right. That was fairly obtuse. :) Surely 'hell' is an accepted word in this context within a quote.

Comment: @Noldorin: It took me a while, before to understand what he meant. I I thought to a word starting with _he_ that could follow _go to_. **:-)**

Comment: "H-E-double hockey sticks" is a common minced oath for *hell* at least in the western US where I grew up, *hell* being considered a curse word when following "go to".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could say that the other person is *acknowledging* the thanks when he says "you're welcome," and perhaps is *rudely dismissing* the thanks when he says "proceed to your choice of unpleasant venue and reside there indefinitely."

Comment: So, "to thank" and "to acknowlege thanks"?

Comment: Yes, I think that works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reciprocal form would be *to receive thanks*.

Comment: One can receive thanks without doing or saying anything in reply, so this does not cover it.

Answer (score 1):

Try unthank, as in “unthank upon the hand that tied him so” - Chaucer, the Miller’s Tale

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the answer!  I'm surprised people are voting you down, you even quoted Chaucer which is as English as it gets.

Comment: but unthank means ungratefulness